# Python 2.7 : pyinstaller create qt.conf file

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, exe, pyinstaller

I am using below command to create an exe file of my python script run.py :

```
pyinstaller.exe --noconsole --onefile  --icon=index.ico run.py
```

It creates an exe file in dist folder and when I double click on this exe file , it also generates an qt.conf file which contents :

```
[Paths]
Prefix = C:/Users/ANUBHA~1.JHA/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI94~1/PyQt4
Binaries = C:/Users/ANUBHA~1.JHA/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI94~1/PyQt4
```

How to stop this qt.conf from being generated and why it is getting generated?

**Info** :

My python script run.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import PySimpleGUI27 as sg
import parse2
import UserList
import UserString

layout = [               
    [sg.Text('A2L File', size=(15, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='right'),      
     sg.InputText('',key='_a2l_'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("A2L File", "*.a2l"),))],
    [sg.Text('Signals Lexicon', size=(15, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='right'),      
     sg.InputText('',key='_sigLex_'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Excel File", "*.xlsx"),))],
    [sg.Text('Parameters Lexicon', size=(15, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='right'),      
     sg.InputText('',key='_parLex_'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Excel File", "*.xlsx"),))],
    [sg.Text('Module Name', size=(15, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='right'),      
     sg.InputText('X',key='_module_'), sg.FolderBrowse()],           
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()],
    [sg.Output(size=(60, 20))]  
]
window = sg.Window('A2L Parser', default_element_size=(40, 1), icon=u'C:\\Users\\anubhav.jhalani\\Desktop\\index.ico').Layout(layout)

values_dict={}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        button, values_dict = window.Read()
        if button=="Cancel" or button is None:
            break
        elif button=='Submit' and (not any(value == '' for value in values_dict.values())):   
            parse2.parser(values_dict['_a2l_'], values_dict['_sigLex_'], values_dict['_parLex_'],window)

        else:
            sg.Popup("Please select files")  

    window.Close()
```

and pyinstaller version : 3.4

Answer (score 1):

The `qt.conf` file seems to only be created when using stock Python or WinPython. It doesn't seem to be created when using Anaconda Python for some reason. Grepping for `qt.conf` in the Pyinstaller source does not give anything.

As a workaround, you can just delete the `qt.conf` file after creating the executable

```
def remove_qt_temporary_files():
    if os.path.exists('qt.conf'):
        os.remove('qt.conf')
```

No deletion

[image]

With deletion

[image]

Example. I'm not 100% sure where the `qt.conf` file is being created but deleting the file at the end seems to work.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui 
import sys
import os

def remove_qt_temporary_files():
    if os.path.exists('qt.conf'):
        os.remove('qt.conf')

class ButtonGrid(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ButtonGrid, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        for i in range(1,5):
            for j in range(1,5):
                self.button_layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton("B"+str(i)+str(j)),i,j)

    def get_layout(self):
        return self.button_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create main application window
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))
    mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    mw.setWindowTitle('Remove qt.conf example')

    # Create button grid widget
    button_grid = ButtonGrid()

    # Create and set widget layout
    # Main widget container
    cw = QtGui.QWidget()
    ml = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    cw.setLayout(ml)
    mw.setCentralWidget(cw)

    ml.addLayout(button_grid.get_layout(),0,0)

    mw.show()
    remove_qt_temporary_files()

    if(sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: Where exactly do you put this code? becuase qt.conf gets generated after double clicking on exe file